# getting "Operation not permitted" while trying to create site-packages inside /usr/lib/python2.7

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

While trying to create directory(site-packages) in `/usr/lib/python2.7`

```
sudo mkdir site-packages
```

I got following error :

```
could not create '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages': Operation not permitted .
```

Any leads to resolve this issue.

Comment: 1) are you sure that `/usr/lib/python2.7` exists? 2) show us the contents of the directory

Comment: This seems like more of a sysadmin issue.